# is there a way to get form responses and place them in specific cell in another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have set up a script that creates a Google form and links it to a spreadsheet, is there a way to collect the responses and place them in certain cells in another sheet then unlinks and deletes the form response sheet.

the script I need will have to be flexible enough that it won't matter what the response sheet is named as I will be making multiple one use forms hence why I would also like to delete the response sheet after the answer is moved

for example say the answer is A (a1), B (b1) and C (c1) and I want to move it to sheet 'C' and into columns F, G and H after that's done i would like the response sheet to unlink and be deleted

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `for example say the answer is A (a1), B (b1) and C (c1) and I want to move it to sheet 'C' and into columns F, G and H after that's done i would like the response sheet to unlink and be deleted`. Can you provide your current script? And can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal? And also, how do you want to run the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue:

You want form response data to be submitted to a sheet of your choice, not the one that is created when linking the form to the spreadsheet.

#### Solution:

In that case, I'd suggest not linking the form to the spreadsheet at all, and use an [onFormSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onformsubmit) trigger to write the submitted data to your desired sheet.

#### Workflow:

1. Install an `onFormSubmit` trigger. You can do that manually, following [these steps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually), or programmatically, by executing this function **once**:

```
const SOURCE_FORM_ID = "YOUR_FORM_ID"; // Change according to your needs

function installOnFormSubmitTrigger() {
  const form = FormApp.openById(SOURCE_FORM_ID);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmitTrigger")
    .forForm(form)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
}
```

2. Once the trigger is installed, a function named `onFormSubmitTrigger` (it doesn't have to be named that way) will execute every time someone submits a response to the form. This function should append the response data to your desired sheet. It could be something like this (check inline comments):

```
const TARGET_SPREADSHEET_ID = "YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID"; // Change according to your needs
const TARGET_SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1"; // Change according to your needs

function onFormSubmitTrigger(e) {
  const targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(TARGET_SPREADSHEET_ID);
  const targetSheet = targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(TARGET_SHEET_NAME);
  if (targetSheet.getLastRow() === 0) { // Add headers if they don't exist yet
    const itemTitles = e.source.getItems().map(item => item.getTitle()); // Get item titles
    itemTitles.unshift("Timestamp"); // Append "Timestamp" to the sheet (if desired)
    targetSheet.appendRow(itemTitles); // Append form item titles to the sheet
  }
  const itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  const responses = itemResponses.map(itemResponse => itemResponse.getResponse()); // Get user responses
  responses.unshift(new Date()); // Add today's date to the responses (if desired)
  targetSheet.appendRow(responses); // Append responses to the sheet
}
```

#### Note:

- If you don't want to submit to the first columns in the spreadsheet, simply add empty strings to the responses array, or use [Range.setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)) instead.

#### Reference:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [appendRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)

Comment: hi @lamblichus, thanks for your help, just a quick question when the response gets submitted the multi choice comes out like this [Ljava.lang.Object;@6179d06d instead of the actual answer, can you provide an example to how to move the responses a couple of columns over

Comment: Hi @banksie I cannot reproduce this, I'm getting the actual answer from a multichoice item. Consider posting a new question with a minimal reproducible example. Also, to shift the results a couple of columns, you can `unshift` a couple of blank strings as well as the `Timestamp`: `itemTitles.unshift("", "", "Timestamp");`. This way, cells A,B remain empty.

Comment: @banksie I saw your question. You are getting this because you don't have a MultipleChoiceItem but a CheckBoxItem, so the item response is an array. It should get solved by checking whether the response is an array, and converting to a string if that's the case, as suggested by Tanaike in that question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69848716/on-form-submit-trigger-giving-weird-results#comment123469230_69848716

Comment: @lamblichus i have tried Tanaike's suggestion and that hasn't worked either, anything that allows multiple answer to be selected doesn't work