# on form submit trigger giving weird results

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a script that creates forms that need to be filled out for ordering, the onformsubmittrigger places this weird line of text when it comes to the multi choice option  **[Ljava.lang.Object;@7c2a6e46**, if possible I would also like to define where the answer are placed instead of the default of column a,b,c

```
function snore() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('TC');
  var value = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var em = sheet.getRange("C2").getValue();
  var cos = sheet.getRange("F2").getValue();
  var name = sheet.getRange("E2").getValue();
  var sup = sheet.getRange("D2").getValue();

  var form = FormApp.create(value);
  var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
  item.setHelpText("Name: " + name +
                 "\n\nEmail: " + em +
                 "\n\nQuote No: " + value +
                 "\n\nProject: " + sup +
                 "\n\nTotal Cost: " + cos +
                 "\n\nBy selecting approve you agree to the cost and timeframe specified by the quote and that the details above are correct")
                 .setChoices([item.createChoice('Approved'), item.createChoice('Denied')]);
  var itm = form.addCheckboxItem();
  itm.setTitle('What extras would you like to add on? (all prices are Ex-GST)');
    itm.setChoices([
        itm.createChoice('Watergate Plus 1370mm x 36.5m, 36.5Lm - $109.80'),
        itm.createChoice('Watergate Plus 2740mm x 30m, 30Lm - $171.60'),
        itm.createChoice('White General Purpose Repair Tape 60mm x 66m, 66Lm - $39.21'),
        itm.createChoice('Wall Wrap, Foil Fasteners, 500/box - $39.21'),
        itm.createChoice('Super Course 500, 300mm x 0.5 x 50Lm - $29.30'),
        itm.createChoice('40mm Metal Top Hat Batten - 3.10/mtr')
    ])
    .showOtherOption(true);
  Logger.log('Published URL: ' + form.getPublishedUrl());
  Logger.log('Editor URL: ' + form.getEditUrl());
  Logger.log('ID: ' + form.getId());

  var myDId = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getId();

  var rootFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(myDId);
  var archiveFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1Rt6xikEpHs-F2cQOTRrvATCZHCFU0bQ6");

  var newForms = rootFolder.getFilesByName(value);
  while (newForms.hasNext()) {
    var newForm = newForms.next();
    archiveFolder.addFile(newForm)
    rootFolder.removeFile(newForm);
  }

  //const spreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  //form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, spreadsheetId);

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('J2').setValue('SENT');

  var id = "1uw8HAJsuNHses_9XGfNtQ71fp3DXE7q1";
  var buildBlob = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob().setName("buildBlob");

  var SendTo = "Jonathon.banks@westal.com.au";

  var link = form.getId();
  var message = "Please follow the link to accept you Quotation " + form.getPublishedUrl();

 //set subject line

  var body = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email");

  body.order = value;
  body.overdue = form.getPublishedUrl();

  var con = sheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(con).next()

 var Subject = 'Quote' + value + 'Confirmation';

  const  recipient = em;
  const subject = "Confirmation of order"

      MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: recipient,
      attachments: file,
      subject: subject,
        htmlBody: body.evaluate().getContent(),
      inlineImages:
      {
      build: buildBlob
    }

      });

  //const subect = "confirm for id"
  //const rcipient = SendTo;
  //var mssage = "please run id confirm " + link;
 //GmailApp.sendEmail(rcipient, subect, mssage)

  const SOURCE_FORM_ID = link; // Change according to your needs

 {
  const form = FormApp.openById(SOURCE_FORM_ID);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmitTrigger")
    .forForm(form)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
  }

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var seet = ss.getSheetByName('TC'); //source sheet
  var testrange = seet.getRange('J:J'); //range to check
  var testvalue = (testrange.getValues());
  var csh = ss.getSheetByName('C'); //destination sheet
  var data = [];
  var j =[];

  //Condition check in H:H; If true copy the same row to data array
for (i=0; i<testvalue.length;i++) {
  if ( testvalue[i] == 'SENT') {
  data.push.apply(data,seet.getRange(i+1,1,1,25).getValues());
  //Copy matched ROW numbers to j
  j.push(i);
 }
 }
//Copy data array to destination sheet

 csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);

//Delete matched rows in the source sheet
  for (i=0;i<j.length;i++){
  var k = j[i]+1;
  sheet.deleteRow(k);

//Alter j to account for deleted rows
  if (!(i == j.length-1)) {
  j[i+1] = j[i+1]-i-1;
}
}
}

//const TARGET_SPREADSHEET_ID = "1JRhCnS048fhWMifkrD1mqdgFcs3-Cw-kGOzSgpLWfI0"; // Change according to your needs
//const TARGET_SHEET_NAME = "C"; // Change according to your needs

function onFormSubmitTrigger(e) {
  const targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1JRhCnS048fhWMifkrD1mqdgFcs3-Cw-kGOzSgpLWfI0");
  const targetSheet = targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("C");
  if (targetSheet.getLastRow() === 0) { // Add headers if they don't exist yet
    const itemTitles = e.source.getItems().map(item => item.getTitle()); // Get item titles
    itemTitles.unshift("Timestamp"); // Append "Timestamp" to the sheet (if desired)
    targetSheet.appendRow(itemTitles); // Append form item titles to the sheet
  }
  const itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  const responses = itemResponses.map(itemResponse => itemResponse.getResponse()); // Get user responses
  responses.unshift(new Date()); // Add today's date to the responses (if desired)
  targetSheet.appendRow([JSON.stringify(responses)])
}
```

Comment: try `targetSheet.appendRow(responses.flat())`

Comment: Or, when you want to put the value from the multi choice option to a cell, how about modifying `targetSheet.appendRow(responses);` to `targetSheet.appendRow(responses.map(e => Array.isArray(e) ? e.join(",") : e));`?

Comment: @TheMaster, thanks for your suggestion but neither worked

Comment: @Tanaike, thanks for your suggestion but it didn't work

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the detailed result from `but neither worked` and `but it didn't work`. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. About `but neither worked` and `but it didn't work` for both suggestions, in this case, both suggestions return the same value of `[Ljava.lang.Object;@7c2a6e46`. Is my understanding correct? And, in order to correctly understand your current situation, can you provide the sample input and output situations as the image? By this, we would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Tanaike here are the links to the screenshots of the form and what comes out the other end [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jPz3_zZRASmSKELS8Qr3IQ2OcfeSg2Ub/view?usp=sharing) and the output [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oq-lH2o0K1zZ52l67M8-s5LWJNbnwOEn/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: It means your are printing an object instead of a string. Try finding the line generating that line and use a method that fetches the object's contents. You might need to loop if the method returns an array, or flatten it by using `flat`

Comment: Thank you for adding more information. When I saw sample input and output, I thought that both TheMaster's and my suggestions can resolve your issue. So both suggestions are not your current output situation like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oq-lH2o0K1zZ52l67M8-s5LWJNbnwOEn/view?usp=sharing). So I cannot understand your current situation. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your issue, when you test `targetSheet.appendRow([JSON.stringify(responses)])` instead of `targetSheet.appendRow(responses)`, what result will you obtain?  By this, we would like to confirm it.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, here is a screenshot of the results when using `targetSheet.appendRow([JSON.stringify(responses)])` [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10XOjRcp5W-K1aqA4CtlLuZELVM0xwbVI/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From `here is a screenshot of the results when using targetSheet.appendRow([JSON.stringify(responses)])`, when `targetSheet.appendRow([JSON.stringify(responses)])` is run, only one value is put. But in your image, 2 values are put. So I'm worried that your updated script might not be used. So how about confirming your script again?

Comment: @Tanaike, in the screenshot , there is a timestamp in A2, in B2 is the reply to the first multiple choice and the jave.lang in C2 is meant to be the answers from the second Multiple choice from the form, i have ran the script again and it has come up with the exact same line of code in C2

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, unfortunately, I think that your script doesn't use `targetSheet.appendRow([JSON.stringify(responses)])`. But I cannot know your actual situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. When I could correctly understand your actual situation, I would like to propose it as an answer. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: @Tanaike, would it be easier if I posted the entire script not just the trigger

Comment: For example, when you reinstall the OnSubmit trigger for the function `onFormSubmitTrigger(e)`, what result will you obtain? At least, I think that your current situation doesn't use `targetSheet.appendRow([JSON.stringify(responses)])`. By this, the multiple answeres are put. And also, for example, can you provide your sample Google Form and Google Spreadsheet including the current script for replicating your issue? By this, I can check it.

Comment: @Tanaike, each time the script creates a new form it runs `onFromSubmitTrigger(e)` creating a new trigger

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `each time the script creates a new form it runs onFromSubmitTrigger(e) creating a new trigger `.

Comment: i have updated the question with the full script, every time I tell the sheet to run the create form script it creates a `onFormSubmitTrigger(e)` that is allocated to the form that was created

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. When I saw your updated script, I think that in your script, the number of `{` is different from `}`. By this, your script cannot be saved. From this situation, I'm confused to think of your current situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. But I would like to try to understand your actual situation. When I could correctly understand your question, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: @Tanaike, I have edited the post to fix the { } issue

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your actual situation. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: all good, thank you for your help

Comment: For some reason the script that is running doesn't include the modification provided by Tanaike. Can you explain the relevance of function `snore`?

Comment: @lamblichus the posted copy has a different fix i was trying at the time, snore is the main function of the script that creates the form whos id is used onformsubmittrigger

Comment: You are not using the script with the modification Tanaike proposed: `targetSheet.appendRow(responses.map(e => Array.isArray(e) ? e.join(",") : e));`. Otherwise, you would be getting the right results. I just tested that. Make sure that you are submitting the right form and executing the right function in the right script.